# Get unique record's in ms access query

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying select the unique records from my table. My table contains nearly 20 columns and more than 500 000 records.

Sample data:

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

I have used the following query, It returns the result which I need but taking lot of time to load the output.

```
SELECT [C1],[C2],[C3],[C4] 
FROM [dbo].[result]
WHERE [C1] = (
    SELECT MIN(C1) 
    FROM [dbo].[result] AS F 
    WHERE F.C2 = [dbo].[result].C2)
```

Is there any way to speed my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
SELECT First([C1]) As Id, [C2], [C3], [C4] 
FROM [dbo].[result]
GROUP BY [C2], [C3], [C4]
```